# Timeshift snapshots randomly disappear on external SSD

Tags: backup, timeshift

I am doing daily back-ups to an external SSD disk, however Timeshift snapshots behave very strangely - for example, I do a back and on the next day that back up is missing, only every now and then a back up is persistent. Does anyone have an idea what might the issue be?

#### Update

Sorry I didn't provide more info, but there is no output/log or anything (at least not that I know of), I am not getting any error, all works, just snapshot is missing on the next day.

I have an external SSD which is of course formatted for linux, type RSYNC, schedule (which I indeed don't understand exactly) I have only `Daily` option ticked with `Keep 3` (I just changed it to 1) [If I understand this correctly, each 3rd day older snapshot would be removed no? Because I have never noticed this behavior). And some directories that are being ignored.

When I connect the SSD and it runs the back up by itself, those are usually persisnant, but I often just connect the SSD, open time-shift and do my manual back-up. Those seem to disappear often.

Once it is finished I just disconnect the SSD.

I am not a Linux pro so if you need some kind of log please point me where could I find it.

Comment: In TS what have you set in `Settings` Schedule tab? Please [edit] in to your question. Also include what device you are backing up to.

Comment: For a question like this, details are very important. Please edit your question to show timeshift output before and after snapshots disappear, and be specific about any manual timeshift actions you took during that time. Also show the setup you have for timeshift - auto or not, how many snapshots, retention policy, etc. Details matter, vague verbal descriptions are pretty useless.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with more details, although it might still not be enough. Let me know. Thanks for helping.